# Sorting value by two columns in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

The idea is to sort value by two columns.
Such that, given two column, I am expecting the output something like

Expected output

```
      x     y
0   2.0   NaN
1   3.0   NaN
2   4.0   4.1
3   NaN   5.0
4  10.0   NaN
5  24.0  24.7
6  31.0  31.4
```

However, using the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame ( {'x': [2, 3, 4, 24, 31, '',10],
                      'y':['','',4.1,24.7,31.4,5,'']} )
df1.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True,inplace=True)
rslt_df = df1.sort_values ( by=['x', 'y'], ascending=(True, True) )

print(rslt_df)
```

Produce the following

```
      x     y
0   2.0   NaN
1   3.0   NaN
2   4.0   4.1
6  10.0   NaN
3  24.0  24.7
4  31.0  31.4
5   NaN   5.0
```

Notice that at the last row, the `5.0` of column `y` is placed at the bottom.

May I know what modification to the code in order to obtained the intended output?

Comment: The reason why is because it's sorting by X (nan goes to bottom), then Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `np.sort` and `argsort`:

```
df1.iloc[np.sort(df1[['x','y']],axis=1)[:,0].argsort()]
```

---

```
      x     y
0   2.0   NaN
1   3.0   NaN
2   4.0   4.1
5   NaN   5.0
6  10.0   NaN
3  24.0  24.7
4  31.0  31.4
```

Comment: This does exactly what the OP intend to with the advantage of being more compact.

Comment: @HenryEcker, I think you should maintain your post. I learn somehting from there.

Answer (score 3):

Try sorting by `x` [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna) `y`, then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) from those sorted values:

```
df1.reindex(df1['x'].fillna(df1['y']).sort_values().index).reset_index(drop=True)
```

To update the `df1` variable:

```
df1 = (
    df1.reindex(df1['x'].fillna(df1['y']).sort_values().index)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

`df1`:

```
      x     y
0   2.0   NaN
1   3.0   NaN
2   4.0   4.1
3   NaN   5.0
4  10.0   NaN
5  24.0  24.7
6  31.0  31.4
```